# What do you call these geometric features? (jut, protrusion, ledge,...)

Tags: meaning, word-request, nouns

What do you call these geometric features?
[image]

If I have it figured out correctly:

- A and B have a *protrusion* or *jut*
- B has a *nose* or a *lug*
- C has a *ledge*

Is that correct? Are there any terms I'm missing? Which terms are preferable? Are there any terms just for what A has?

Comment: As geometric shapes I don't believe the orientation will matter: if A has a protrusion, so does C (and B, for that matter). Have you looked up the definitions of all those words? If so, why and how is it unclear?

Comment: The orientation can matter if we assume real world objects with gravity pointing down. In that case A can be said to have an "overhang".

Comment: I don't think any of those terms are as specific as you are making them sound.  For example, a [*lug*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/lug) is just a kind of projection, not something distinct from "a projection", and is defined more by *use* than by *shape*.